# How can I print full path of an executable command in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, path

At the moment when trying to run `tf` command and/or any other run-able command, I need to open Visual Studio Command to get it executable. I like to use the normal console and/or the [alternative console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) but failed to call `tf`.

So, I need to print the full path of `tf` and any runable-command but don't know how to do so.

Please help.

Comment: The poster is looking for the equivalent of the "which" command in some Unix shells, e.g. "which grep" prints the full path of the grep command that the shell will execute in response to you typing "grep" without a path.  I'm looking for this too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but judging by your comments, you may be looking for `where`.

```
where foo

where foo | clip
```

The second example will place the whole path into the clipboard.

If I remember correctly, `where.exe` needs to be added to XP/2003 from the Windows 2003 Resource Kit or XP Support Tools.

Comment: It comes preinstalled with Windows 7. There is also a [script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/20/357225.aspx) for older Windows versions.

Comment: There is also a where.exe in UnxUtils, along with lot of useful Unix commands.

Comment: @PhiLho: The original Unix version is `which`.

Comment: ouch, `where.exe` lives in system32, my bad... Funnily, I just tried them to find java.exe, `where` points to the JDK path (that's the one Windows finds) while `which` points to system32, earlier in the path. But it doesn't exist there, there might be a hardlink there, or something similar. Well, back to the topic, `which`, roughly similar to `where`, can be found in a free package.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.80).aspx), you should find `tf` in  `<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio x\Common7\IDE`.

(I've substituted *x* in the version because I don't know which version you're using.)

---

EDIT:

According to the [Walkthrough: Working with Team Foundation Source Control from Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthc5x3f(v=vs.80).aspx), (and assuming VS 2005), you can access the tools for TF at the following path:

`<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools`

Comment: @Potter: Thank you! How about any other run-able commands that were added in the system environment variable `PATH`? Should it be a quick command to print their full path?

Comment: Are you talking about Team Foundation executables specifically?

Comment: @Potter: No. I'm talking about a general executable command.

Answer (score 1):

`where.exe` as mentioned in one of the comments does come with Windows 7 and higher. Another thing to note is that `where` **only** searches the `%PATH%` so if your program isn't in the path it won't help you locate it.

Another problem is if you happen to be trying to invoke it from within a PowerShell prompt you **NEED** to include the .exe portion, as "where" is an alias for Where-Object which is NOT what you want, and leads to empty results with success codes that obviously don't tell you where the application you want is actually located.

This took me a few tries to figure out, and only appending `-?` which triggered help on what the alias actually resolved to clued me in.

Per your question, the reason `tf` works from within the Visual Studio application/console, there is a specific shortcut they include to launch a Visual Studio console because it adds the application's folders to the PATH when launched.

You can define your own shortcut to inject the program's directory into your `PATH`, or just open the Start Menu, type "env" and click the shortcut "Edit environment variables for your account" (or the system one, but that requires you to click on the Environment Variables button), then add a new `PATH` variable at the top under User Variables if it doesn't exist, or if it already exists add a `;` before your entry and then the complete folder path where the program you want to call from the command line lives. E.g. double click the `PATH` entry (case doesn't matter much on Windows) to edit and change it to `C:\ExistingPathItem\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio 2020\bin`